# Calculating combined percentiles?

Tags: statistics

How to calculate combined percentile in the following case? Suppose some GMAT-like test result is expressed in two number, V (0-100) and Q (0-100). And to calculate the total score, a simple arithmetic mean is used (V+Q)/2. Now Alice has a score of V in the 75th percentile and Q score in the 60th percentile. Is/when is it possible to combine the two to get her total score's percentile?